# How to pass multiple datas(radio button value, 2selection box option value) in a single anchor tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

### passing multiple values in anchor tag href using jquery

- country name
- state name
- quetion_id(radio button)
- one anchor tag (options)

  When i click the anchor tag , it should take the county name ,state name and question id , it passes to the href link .
  How to use this in jquery

  ```
  <select id="country">
              <option value='India'>INDIA</option>
              <option value='Usa'>USA</option>
   </select>
   <select id="state">
              <option value='karnataka'>karnataka</option>
              <option value='Tamilnadu'>Tamilnadu</option>
    </select>
  <input type='radio' name='ques_id' id='quest_id'>
  <a href='#' id='option_link'></a>
  ```

How to pass all this in jquery and also it should validate the radio button

I have tried something

```
{
var opt_value;
$("#option_link").change(function(){
  country_value = $('#country').val();
  state_value = $('#state').val();
  question_value = $('#ques_id').val();

   function()
    {
     $('#option_link').attr('href','/options?id='+____________); 
 });
}
```

Comment: can you include to your question your html code / elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this :

$("#option_link").click(function(e){

       country_value = $('#country').val();
       state_value = $('#state').val();
       question_value = $('input[name=ques_id]:checked').val();

       $('#option_link').attr('href','/options?id='+question_value+'&country='+country_value+'&state_value='+state_value); 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create a string and pass it in jQuery.

```
 str='/options?id='+country_value+'_'+state_value+'_'+question_value; 
 $('#option_link').attr('href',str);
```

You have not added value to radio field.